# Database how add data without overwriting?

Tags: java, mysql, database, file, filereader

I have a text file looks like:

```
    george   19   180     75
    paul     20   182     84
    laura    21   176     73
    ...      ...  ...     ...
```

In my program I read this file and add its content to a table in my database which has parameters(name, age, height, weight). The code looks like

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {

    PreparedStatement preparedstatement = null;

    try{
        String read=null;
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("patientlist.txt")); 
        while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splited = read.split("\\s+");
            name=splited[0];
            age=splited[1];
            height=splited[2];
            weight=splited[3];      
            addpatient(connection, preparedstatement, name, age, height, weight);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);}
        if (connection != null)
        try{connection.close();} catch(SQLException ignore){} 
    }

    public static void addpatient(Connection connection, PreparedStatement preparedstatement, String name, String age, String height, String weight) throws SQLException{
    preparedstatement=connection.prepareStatement("insert into allpatients(name, age, height, weight) values(?,?,?,?)");
    preparedstatement.setString(1, name);
    preparedstatement.setString(2, age);
    preparedstatement.setString(3, height);
    preparedstatement.setString(4, weight);
    preparedstatement.executeUpdate();

    }
```

When I run this code this adds george, paul to name column etc.
But my problem is when I add a new entry to my file like:

```
   Rachel   20   175  78
```

and run the program again, it adds all the values into my database again but I just want to add the newest entry. How can I do that. Is there something like append? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might find this interesting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

First thing, in your code prepared statement has no significance meaning. Means every time prepared statement is created when you call the `addpatient` method. Besides that you can do like this :

```
In your main method :
{
    preparedstatement=connection.prepareStatement("insert into allpatients(name, age, height, weight) values(?,?,?,?)");

   //Your rest code comes here

    addPatient(preparedstatement,name,age,height,weight);
}

public static void addPatient(PreparedStatment preparedstatement, String name, String age, String height, String weight ){
    preparedstatement.setString(1, name);
    preparedstatement.setString(2, age);
    preparedstatement.setString(3, height);
    preparedstatement.setString(4, weight);
    preparedstatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

And every time you execute the addPatient method, it adds records in current table only.

Comment: No what I meant was when I run for the first time it adds the current names and ages etc to the database. I want them to stay in the database. And from another program I put another entry to the file. When I run this program again I want the first records to stay and just add the new entry to my database

Comment: @Solijoli check my answer. And if you are creating the table in the application then you might face the problem.

Answer (score -1):

u can try preparedstatement.clearBatch() method
and when u finished a jdbc commit,u should close it.
The connection object has close() method;

I suggested that if u have many data to store in one time u can use addBatch() method with PreparedStatement.

Comment: I close the connection, that is in the if statement in my code. Where should I put clearBatch(), I don't know how that works actually but it sounds like it can work